# PHP IMAP get message preview without whole body text

Tags: php, imap

Using the PHP `IMAP` library, is it possible to grab just the first 100 characters or so of the message body without grabbing the whole message?

I'm working on a message preview feature, and I don't want to make the user wait for the entirety of every message to load before he/she gets to see the preview.

EDIT:
Why was my thanks removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. But what you *can* do, however, is fetch certain part of the message body with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php